# MVC Controller is not receiving the values that comes from the Ajax /Javascript script

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I debugged the JS and Ajax code with console.log. I can see that what I entered into the textbox, is displayed in the console. However, when these values are supposed to send to the controller, they are empty or null when I hover over the tbl_stuff List. Not sure where I am making a mistake.

Here is the JS:

```
      $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
    var table = $("table tbody");
    var array= new Array();
    table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        Amount = $(this).find('.val').val();
        valuestoupdate = { Amount: amount };
        array.push(valuestoupdate);
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("StuffAction","Home")",
        data: JSON.stringify(array),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r + " record(s) saved.");
        }
    });
```

Here is the controller action:

```
     public JsonResult StuffAction(List<tbl_Stuff> stuffs)
    {
        int getID = (int)TempData["id"];
        TempData.Keep();
        var GetData = _context.tbl_Detail.Where(x => x.detId == getID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (GetData != null)
        {              
            foreach (tbl_Stuff moreThings in stuffs)
            {
                tbl_Stuff stuff = new tbl_Stuff();                    
                stuff.Amount = moreThings.Amount;
                _context.tbl_Stuff.Add(stuff);
            }
        }
        int insertedRecords = _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json(insertedRecords);
    }
```

I get an error saying that moreThings.Amount is empty. But during debugging, the JS code gets the value entered into the textbox.

Comment: Can you share your json object that is being posted to your controller?

Comment: `Val` is undefined.
`GetData` is a good name for a method, not a local variable. Perhaps `detail` will be better here.

Comment: @klekmek, added the html part as well. The array its sending is ['undefined', '123']. '123' is the value that I type into the txtbox to save in the db.

Comment: You should be sending an array of objects that correspond with `tbl_Stuff`. Not it's just an array of strings. ASP.NET using model binding, so try to create your json object to represent what you are expecting in your controller.

Comment: @klekmek how do I do this?

Comment: Can you try with **JSON.stringify({ stuffs: array})** Assuming the `tbl_Stuff` has simple structure with `Amount` property. Because if it is more then you'd need to match that in your javascript.

Comment: I tried this ;line above the Ajax: var thingy = JSON.stringify(customers). And changed this data: thingy, too inside the Ajax post  but it does the same thing. And I only want to send that Amount value to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net routing can't match the request

change the action signature to  **public JsonResult StuffAction(List< string > stuffs)**

or in your ajax call change the array to an array of **objects matching the properties** of **tbl_Stuff**

Comment: How can this be achieved in Ajax? How do I change the list its sending?

Comment: array.push({prop:val});
where prop is the property of tbl_stuff name starting with lower case

Comment: I've updated my code, see above, but now instead of  ['undefined', '123'] this being sent to the controller, this gets sent  ['undefined', 123] which is probably right but in the controller - > List<tbl_stuff> stuffs is now null and not even null with the 2 variables that  were null like before.